# 404 when Previewing an unsaved draft

Tags: customization, 404-error, previews

I just started at a new job and I'm being thrown into some pretty heavy WordPress bugs on their heavily modified system. Basically what's going on is that they have their own CMS that handles most of a site, but if I site has a blog we inject wordpress there. The backend of all the sites (including the WP admin backend) is running off of one domain. Then we have the blog and site itself on a separate domain.

So basically what I can deduce is happening is that the user session isn't being carried over from the backed to the frontend for the preview. Does anyone here have any thoughts about how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Open the wp-config file and replace the line that reads `define('WP_DEBUG', false);` with:

```
if ( isset($_GET['debug']) && $_GET['debug'] == '1' ) {
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
} elseif ( isset($_GET['debug']) && $_GET['debug'] == '2' ) {
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true);
} elseif ( isset($_GET['debug']) && $_GET['debug'] == '3' ) {
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
}
```

After adding the above code to the `wp-config file`, saving it and replacing the original config file, you can add `?debug=1` to the end of the Admin URL of the specific page your on when getting the error. You can also enable a php-error file which can be useful in troubleshooting problems:

- Create a file named `php-errors.log`
  Place this code before the *OK Stop Editing* line in the `wp-config.php` file:

  @ini_set('log_errors','On');

  @ini_set('display_errors','Off');

  @ini_set('error_log','/home/your-wordpress-files-folder/php-errors.log'); // path to log file

With any luck the errors will point you in the right direction to fix the problem.